# How can I display lsp info of current file configured by coc-nvim extension?

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm new to coc-nvim, and I am used to the combination lspconfig + mason. Before I switch to coc, `:LspInfo` command will show the enabled lsp for current file, while it does not show the one configured by coc extensions.

I am looking for an equivalent coc command that does the same job of `:LspInfo`

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And reading the documentation of that plugin would be out of the question, right?

Comment: @romainl I did read the doc of coc-nvim as well as those lsp-extensions, that is how I configured my nvim and make it work well by so far. But I honestly couldn't find the solution for this question. If by any chance you still remember the command, or at least a possible url for me to look through, I would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`:CocList services` will list activated server for current buffer.